# Unique key for each row in a repeater field

Tags: php, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

Is it possible to have a unique key for each sub fields in a repeater field? I don't want to use the array index, because the array index can be changed, when adding new rows between existing rows.

I have checked the meta keys in the database, but the meta keys are changing too. Can anyone help me how I can solve this?

Comment: How is this repeater field being created? Please show some code.

Comment: I forgot to tell that i'm using ACF and the plugin Repeater field.

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I was looking for a similar solution and found this plugin: https://github.com/KLicheR/wp-acf-unique_id